# dimple.js plots the wrong values

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, plot, dimple.js

We are trying to develop a chart which plots a weather file with its corresponding relative humidity and temperature values. So far the chart generates itself correctly, and plots the current weather data based on your location, but it does not plot typical yearly weather data for the current location.

The correct array is written to console, but when handed to dimple to plot, the data that ends up on the chart is not the same as the data logged in console. it is usually significantly higher.

We are having trouble with the code starting on line 171.
See below link:
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrowse/bnq419qx/1/

This could be a problem with a conflict between d3.csv and dimple, or dimple being handed such a large number of points to plot.

It is just the function starting from line 171 ending on line 193 that is giving us issues:

```
d3.csv("http://psychrometric.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/HourlyWeatherFiles/GBR_London.Gatwick.037760_IWEC.csv", function (data) {
// console.log(data);
var hourlydata = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //console.log(data[i]);
    var rh = parseFloat(data[i].rh);
    var dbt = parseFloat(data[i].dbt);
    hourlydata.push({
        "Relative Humidity": rh,
        "Dry-Bulb Temperature": dbt,
        "Moisture Content": psy.convert(rh, dbt, "rh", "w")
    });
}
    console.log("*********************************");
console.log(hourlydata);
var hourlySeries = myChart.addSeries("Relative Humidity", dimple.plot.bubble, [xAxis, yAxis]);
hourlySeries.data = hourlydata;
hourlySeries.radius= 3;
drawChart();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are those "issues"?

Comment: the values that console logs are not the values that get plotted

Comment: Well it'd help a lot if you could give a specific example. There are thousands of points in that array, and it's not at all clear how to relate any object logged to the console with something in the graph.

Comment: I would, but the size of the array is part of the problem, If I just plot the first ten lines of the massive array it still doesn't plot quite right. I search for the asterisks then look at the next line when using jsfiddle as its constantly logging stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is aggregating your series. It appears the default aggregation is to sum all records whenever the x-axis values match before displaying. You can override that behavior by defining an aggregation on your series as described here: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.series#aggregate

Another thing you might want to explore is the 'stacked' option, though that doesn't appear to help for reasons I can't understand at the moment: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.series#stacked

Comment: I have set aggregatemethod to average to begin with. And this looks how it should, if I plot in excel. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrowse/bnq419qx/
Dimple is a little too sophisticated for its own good. I will need some kind of custom aggregate method to get dimple to plot the data as it is, with no processing. At the moment as I understand it, it is finding duplicate data points and performing uneeded average operations on it. There is a tonne of ways to make this all faster, at least I have an Intermediate fix

Comment: I think the 'stacked' option should let you tell it not to aggregate, but it has no effect when I try it. :-/ Good luck!